# Downloaded module not found in IDLE

Tags: machine-learning, module

I am trying to use some libraries I downloaded, [but whenever I check for them in IDLE I don't see them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUVcY.png)

The same thing happens when I type from sklearn import datasets

[But when I try to pip install I see this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDuFs.png)
Does this mean I am limited to only the Spyder IDE?

Answer (score 0):

There are somehow distinct distributions of Python that you seem to be running. I would suggest using virtualenv and running your IDE (idle/others) via that. Here's a tutorial video for it. [1]

[1] https://teamtreehouse.com/library/idle-in-a-virtual-environment-2